# which email service are used in CloudFoundry in general?

Tags: java, vmware, cloud-foundry

I am trying to implement email service for my project in cloudfoundry. does anyone have any idea about the email services that are used in cloudfoundry in general and how ?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no support for email within Cloud Foundry itself. I would suggest using a mail service like [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/).

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. Could you please help me by providing code snippet,sample config files to show how to use SendGrid in spring application ?

Comment: * Googles 'sendgrid java example' * http://sendgrid.com/docs/Code_Examples/java.html

Answer (score 1):

You can send email in CloudFoundry through AlphaMail. See my blog post: http://www.jiwhiz.com/post/2012/11/Send_Email_Through_AlphaMail_Inside_CloudFoundry